# Add new submodule to the place of an old submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in this folder `abc/submodule` , I remove it with these commands:

```
rm -rf abc/submodule
# remove submodule in .gitmodules
# remove submodule in .git/config
git rm --cached abc/submodule
git push origin master
```

Now I want to add new submodule to the same place:

```
git submodule add <link> abc/submodule
```

The content of the old submodule appears instead of the new one. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`git submodule` stores the Git info in `$toplevel/.git/modules/$sm_path`. To fully remove it, you will need to remove that directory. You should be able to do the following commands:

```
repo="submodule"
rm -rf $(cd $repo && git rev-parse --git-dir)
rm -rf $repo
git rm --cached "$repo"
git config --remove-section submodule."$repo"
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule."$repo"
```

This is an extension to `git submodule deinit`, which only does the opposite of `git submodule init`.

Note that you will need to commit before pushing as well (those changes were only staged).